# simple Codeigniter suggestion

Tags: php, codeigniter

Version: CodeIgniter-2.2.4

I have solid understand of PHP and some basic of OOP. I'm beginner user of Codeigniter. I downloded Codeigniter and unzipped. I created a folder and named "first_application" on my "htdocs" folder. I edited only database.php and entered database host to "localhost", database user to "root" database password is blank.

Database name ="first_application".

Then, I created a controler class named Hello_world.php . Here is code..

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed);
class Hello_world extends CI_Controller {
    function index()
    {   
        $data['title']='My first application';
        $data['message']='My name is samol';
        $this->load->view('helloworld', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

And then created a file on "views" folder.  Here is code..

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echt $title;?></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<h1><?php echo $message?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I entered on my browser http://localhost/first_application/index.php/Hello_world  . And i have seen this error message.

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'title' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\first_application\application\controllers\Hello_world.php on line 6`

I explored many tutorials site and read many PDF book but i did not get sucess.  Give me some suggestion to override this problem.

Comment: check all syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

```
<title><?php echt $title;?></title>
```

should be:

```
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a single quote

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed);
```

should be

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed');
```

(after the allowed word, to end the string with a single quote), not sure if that was a mistake on your part placing it into stackoverflow, or if that was your actual script code, because that is still a syntax error, only way to know, is if that code is on the same line as the error.

**However that isnt the syntax error in question, @nikolas described the correct one, but just to note that there is another error on this page.**

Comment: Nope. This is just answer to question because error says that parser expects closing bracket at least. This is line six in controller. Little advice to @Hassem Uddin use code editor / IDE that can show you distinctive part of code. Check here all strings are green. That should be indicator something is not right.

Comment: I use notepad++ and Dreamweaver cc. It was a mistook . Code is fine but same problem.